# Trying to get an id from an array of objects with cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have to find a id from an array of objects with id, emails, birthday, etc
but i end up getting in the way

I thought of getting the index returned from the array, that has the right email/user (i.g: c@c.com),
and then accessing and returning the id, or something like that

How can i do it properly?

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getId', (user, passwd) => {
    // user = c@c.com
    let arr = []
    cy.getToken(user, passwd).then(token => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url:'/users',
            headers:{ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
        }).its('body.data.data').then((list) => Cypress._.map(list, 'email')).should('contain', 'c@c.com')
            .then(res => arr.push(res))
    }).then(() => {
       index = cy.log(arr.indexOf("c@c.com"))
       return index
    })//.its('body.id').then(id => {
        //return id
    //})
})
```

but this index return -1, and if i do `cy.log(arr)` returns the proper array, so i can't test if i can access the body.id by it

[image]

[image]

My getToken code:

```js
    Cypress.Commands.add('getToken', (user, passwd) => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/auth/login',
        body: {  
            email: user,
            password: passwd
        }
    }).its('body.data.token').should('not.be.empty') 
    .then(token => {
       return token
    })
} )
```

Comment: You're pushing into the array in an asynchronous function, but trying to access it before the async function has completed.

Comment: @Barmar isn't  it  (then() => {}) preventing this from happening?

Comment: [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your results array nested within another array.

See screen grab shows `[Array(8)]` and item 0 is `['Leon', ...`

So either:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getId", (user, passwd) => {

  let arr = []
  cy.getToken(user, passwd)
    .then((token) => {
      cy.request({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/users",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .its("body.data.data")
      .then((list) => Cypress._.map(list, "email"))
      .should("contain", "c@c.com")
      .then((res) => arr.push(res));
    })
    .then(() => {
      index = arr[0].indexOf("c@c.com")
      cy.log(index)
      return index;
    }); 
})
```

or:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getId", (user, passwd) => {

  cy.getToken(user, passwd)
    .then((token) => {
      cy.request({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/users",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .its("body.data.data")
      .then((list) => Cypress._.map(list, "email"))
      .should("contain", "c@c.com")
    })
    .then(arr => {
      index = arr.indexOf("c@c.com")
      cy.log(index)
      return index;
    }); 
})
```

Also `.then((list) => Cypress._.map(list, "email"))` is dubious, the "email" is supposed to be a function.

Answer (score 0):

[`cy.log()` yields null.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/log#Yields) Try just returning the value instead of the one assigned.

```js
.then(() => {
  return arr.indexOf("c@c.com")
});
...
```